# fetch core data string and place in a label (Swift4)

Tags: core-data, label, swift4, fetch, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to call 2 different core data strings and place them each on separate labels. Right now I am getting the error Cannot invoke initializer for type 'init(_:)' with an argument list of type '([NSManagedObject])'. This error is coming from  j1.text = String(itemsName). I added both view controllers for saving and displaying.

```
        import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var j1 : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var j2 : UITextField!


@IBAction func save(){

    let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Team", in : context)!

    let theTitle = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    theTitle.setValue(j1.text, forKey: "score")
    theTitle.setValue(j2.text, forKey: "alba")


    do {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("Tom Corley")

    }
}}
class twoVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var j1 : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var j2 : UILabel!

        var itemsName : [NSManagedObject] = []
      var itemsName2 : [NSManagedObject] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Team")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "score", ascending: true)]


        let fetchRequest2 = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Team")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "alba", ascending: true)]





        do {
            itemsName = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            itemsName2 = try context.fetch(fetchRequest2)
            if let score = itemsName[0].value(forKey: "score") {
                j1.text = (score as! String)
            }
            if let alba = itemsName2[0].value(forKey: "alba") {
                j2.text = (alba as? String)
            }


        }catch {
            print("Ashley Tisdale")
        }
    }}
```

Comment: You are getting this error because `itemsName` and `itemsName2` are array and there is no String init available that accept array as argument, can you please give more detail of what you want that can help us to understand what you want

Comment: @NiravD I am trying to call 2 different arrays from core data and display them on separate labels. The core Data Strings are alba and score.

Comment: You are still not getting, what i'm saying is how can you display array in label also the array is type of `NSManagedObject`, can you show your Team entity

Comment: @NiravD I updated my question with all of my code. That should answer your question.

Comment: Now you are setting value from first object but your app may crash if your array is empty if you want to show all the data what you need is to use tableView search about it and you will know how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the result from the fetch and append to a string that is then used as value for the label, this goes inside the `do{...}` where you do the fetch today. Note that I am only using one fetch request here.

```
itemsName = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
var mergedScore: String = ""
var mergedAlba: String = ""
for item in itemsName {
    if let score = item.value(forKey: "score") as? String {
         mergedScore.append(score)
         mergedScore.append(" ") //separator
    }
    if let alba = item.value(forKey: "alba") as? String {
         mergedScore.append(alba)
         mergedScore.append(" ") //separator
    }
}
j1.text = mergedScore
j2.text = mergedAlba
```

Comment: What function do I put this in?

Comment: The one in your question , replace the existing lines with it

Comment: Its starting to work but Its only displaying the first index. I want to display everything in the array.

Comment: @SamBurns I intentionally only read the first value in my answer because I didn’t know exactly what you wanted. Do I understand it correctly that you want to add all fetched values to the label?

Comment: I want to fetch all of the values to the label.

Comment: Something is wrong in line j1.text = itemsName.map( {$0.value(forKey: "score"} ).joined(", "). Specifically the "score"} part.

Comment: I didn't convert it into a string like in the first version, have you tried that? `String($0.value(forKey: "score"))`

Comment: I tried  j1.text = String($0.value(forKey: "score")) and it does not work

Comment: @SamBurns Oh come on man, I meant that you should use it inside the last answer I gave

Comment: I dont know what your talking about the last answer. Are you talking about the first or second box.

Comment: The second box is not working its causing this error Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Any?)'.

Comment: What type is score and alba?

Comment: They are both Strings

Comment: The .joined(", ") is causing a error stating Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: That's because the result of `map()` is of type `[Any]` so it needs a cast

Comment: @SamBurns The answer was update with what I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @SamBurns, I see you have a bounty on this question now, care to tell me why my answer didn’t work?

Comment: @SamBurns, one more try to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one it's Working for me Swift 4** I think You need to store the value as int which are used as sortDescriptor.

```
func FetchManagedObjectFromDatabaseForStoreData(Entity :NSEntityDescription) -> 
[NSManagedObject]
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()

    // Add Sort Descriptor
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "is_favourite", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor1]

    // Create Entity Description
    fetchRequest.entity = Entity

    let result : [NSManagedObject] = []

    // Execute Fetch Request
    do{
        let result = try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]

    if  result.count > 0
    {
        return result

    }
    else
    {
        // return result

    }
}
catch{
    let fetchError = error as NSError
    print(fetchError)
}

return result
}
```

**For Fetch Data**

```
// Create Entity Description
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Your Entity Name Here", in: appDel.managedObjectContext)

let DataObject = FetchManagedObjectFromDatabaseForStoreData(Entity: entityDescription!)

//Convert  Array of NSManagedObject into array of [String:AnyObject]     
for item in DataObject{

    let keys = Array(item.entity.attributesByName.keys)

    // Here is your result
    print((item.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: keys) as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "id") as Any) // And so On Whatewer you Fetch

}
```

Comment: I am confused on what to put in result.count >0. I tried     itemsName = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                itemsName2 = try context.fetch(fetchRequest2)
                j1.text = String(itemsName)
                j2.text = String(itemsName2)
                but I am getting the same error.

Comment: @SamBurns Here itemsName and itemsName2 is not String type it's NSManagedObject so you need to convert it same like I have done in an Updated answer. Try it :)