# Fetched data from core data missing some info

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have two entities in my core data model: CardCollection (class name CardCollectionMO) and Card (CardMO). A CardCollection can have many cards. Here's my code for saving the CardCollection with a set of new cards, which seems to be working correctly.

```
func saveCardInfo() {

    let currentDate = createDate()
    let collectionNumber = arc4random_uniform(1000000)

    let cardcollection = CardCollectionMO.insertNewCollection(collectionNumber: Int64(collectionNumber), collectionTitle: collectionTitle.text!, collectionDescription: collectionDescription.text!, numberOfCards: Int16(cards.count), dateCreated: String(currentDate))

    var newCard = Set<CardMO>()

    for card in cards {

        if let addedCard = CardMO.insertNewCard(questionText: card.questionText, answerText: card.answerText, cardNum: Int16(card.cardNum), questionImage: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(card.questionImage, 1)! as NSData) {

            addedCard.cardcollection = cardcollection
            newCard.insert(addedCard)
        }
    }
    cardcollection?.addToCards(newCard as NSSet)
}
```

But, strange things happen when fetching the data back. Here's the code.

```
func fetchData() {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<CardCollectionMO>(entityName: "CardCollection")

    do {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {
            for result in results {

                if let collectionTitle = result.collectionTitle {

                    print(collectionTitle)
                }

                if let listOfCards = result.cards?.allObjects as? [CardMO] {

                    for card in listOfCards {

                        if let questionText = card.questionText {

                            print(questionText)

                        }
                    }
```

The code above works fine while the app is running but if I stop and restart the app, the last card in each collection is removed. I've done a listOfCards.count and its like it doesn't exist. But, if I just fetch all the cards from the Card entity, they're there. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong and why the last card in the collection isn't being fetched?

Comment: **Try this it's Working** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51700569/10150796

Comment: Tip: If you have created an inverse relationship it’s enough to set one side of the relationship - the other is being setup automatically.

Comment: Have you verified each card gets properly stored in `saveCardInfo()` (`CardMO.insertNewCard` is successful for each card)?