# Core Data - One to Many relationship fetch AND filter via property

Tags: swift, core-data, filter, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

My Data Model

[image]

A Client can have many Assessments but an Assessment can only have one Client as an inverse relationship. My aim is to fetch all the Assessments that a Client has and also filter based on the "firstName" property of the initial Client.

My Filter Function:

```
  func filterData(){

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let words = textInSearchField.components(separatedBy: " ")

for word in words{

  if (word).count == 0{
    continue
  }

  let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName contains[c] %@", word)
  let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName contains[c] %@", word)
  let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id contains[c] %@", word)

  // I am using a Compound Predicate so that I can filter by first name, last name but also the id property.
  let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.or, subpredicates: [firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate, idPredicate])

  clientsEntity.predicate = orPredicate

  // results is an array of type [NSManagedObject], I am using the compound predicate I created above to fetch specific clients. 
  results = try! context.fetch(clientsEntity) as! [NSManagedObject]

 }
}
```

I essentially want to get all the Assessments of a Client filtering by the firstName, lastName or ID. Is NSPredicate the best approach?

Thank you.

Comment: By using this you can fetch all filter data from core data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51700569/10150796

Comment: Fetch the client and get `assessed_by`.